# Wikitravel dump

Tags: export, wikitravel

[Wikitravel](http://wikivoyage.org/) is a wiki for tourism information.

The content's license is open, but I can't find data dumps.

How/where can I can reasonably fresh dumps (wikicode of the articles) of the data?

*Note: I need this data to update my project, the [OxygenGuide](http://code.google.com/p/oxygenguide/) portable travel guide.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community has switched to Wikivoyage, which provides regular data dumps:

http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwikivoyage/

Comment: This is the correct answer! We ended up using WikiVoyager for our travel website http://www.wikinomad.com

Comment: @GaneshKrishnan: Given the structure of your website, you might find it easier to use Wikivoyage's structured database of points of interest: https://github.com/baturin/wikivoyage-listings#download-latest-ready-to-use-data

Comment: Amazing work! Thank you so much for pointing it out. I really appreciate it

Comment: @GaneshKrishnan You're welcome! Don't hesitate to fix all errors you find directly in Wikivoyage, so that the data improves :-)

Comment: Sure will ;) I am linking wikivoyager from my site wikiNomad.com

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://wikitravel.org/en/Wikitravel%3aDatabase_dump) on the Wikitravel site:

> There are currently no database dumps of Wikitravel available for
>   download. Some people have asked to make dumps available.

However, the article does go on to state:

> **Reasons to make dumps available**
>
> - makes it easier for other sites to use WT info
> - will make the Offline_Reader_Expedition successful
> - see http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps
> - the lack of database dumps may lead to project forks
>
> **Reasons not to make dumps available**
>
> - None?

So it looks like it is a work in progress at the moment. You could always sign up to help with the process of creating the data dumps.

Alternatively, you could use their [API](http://wikitravel.org/wiki/en/api.php) which is [mentioned on this page.](http://wikitravel.org/shared/How_to_re-use_Wikitravel_guides)

> **API**
>
> A MediaWiki API for programmatic access to the site is available at
>   http://wikitravel.org/wiki/code/api.php, where code is one of the
>   language versions of Wikitravel, eg. "en" for English. When using the
>   API, please follow the [terms of use](http://wikitravel.org/en/Terms_of_use) and download no more than one
>   article every 30 seconds, or you may be blocked without warning.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently http://wikitravel.org/wiki/code/api.php has been removed (error 404). I guess there is a kind of conflict between the company that runs Wikitravel's servers and the Wikitravel editors community, resulting in rather contradicting statements. Maybe somebody is already doing regular wikicode-fetching crawling and making datadumps available to all somewhere? That would be great as well.

Comment: No the API, is still available. You have to replace `code` with the corresponding language code.  So for English, you would have to use http://wikitravel.org/wiki/en/api.php Not sure what the valid list of language codes are though.

Comment: Ah thanks! Sorry for not reading fully, I just clicked the link without thinking further...

Comment: Not a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a dumping project myself.
I made the download script open source, and the data is downloadable:

http://code.google.com/p/oxygenpump/